# Simple html dom find strong

Tags: dom

```
<tr>
<td width="70"><strong>Director:</strong></td>
<td><a href="/?&director=Zhangke Jia">Zhangke Jia</td>
</tr>
```

I try to do this parser but not working

```
foreach($html->find('strong.Director:') as $titlu) {
echo $titlu->find('a', 0)->plaintext;

}
```

In need some help please

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because 'Director' is not a class name, It's just a text inside 'td > strong' tag.

These are the ways you can find html dom elements:

- Finding HTML elements by id
- Finding HTML elements by tag name
- Finding HTML elements by class name
- Finding HTML elements by HTML object collections

try this:

foreach($html->find('td a') as $titlu) {
      echo $titlu->plaintext;
}